# Install PyQt5 and sip fail

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pyqt5

I created a virtual enviroment with python 2.7 like this:
    virtualenv py_env

Then I wanted to install SIP (sip-4.19.1) and PyQt5 (PyQt-gpl-5.5.1)
, so I downloaded both (riverbankcomputing) and tried to intall them like so:

```
cd py_env
cd sip-4.19.1/
python configure --incdir=../include/python2.7/
make
sudo make install
```

This worked fine and python confirms that sip now can be imported:

```
>>> import sip
>>> sip
<module 'sip' from 
'/home/robin/Develop/py_todo_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/sip.so'>
```

Next, I did this to intall PyQt5:

```
cd ../PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/
python configure --sip-incdir=../include/sip/
make
ERROR!!!
```

There where errors when running make:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -
DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o qpycore_types.o ../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp: In function ‘int pyqtWrapperType_init(pyqtWrapperType*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp:160:5: error: ‘pyqt5ClassTypeDef’ was not declared in this scope
     pyqt5ClassTypeDef *pyqt_td = (pyqt5ClassTypeDef *)((sipWrapperType *)self)->type;
     ^
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp:160:24: error: ‘pyqt_td’ was not declared in this scope
     pyqt5ClassTypeDef *pyqt_td = (pyqt5ClassTypeDef *)((sipWrapperType *)self)->type;
                        ^
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp:160:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     pyqt5ClassTypeDef *pyqt_td = (pyqt5ClassTypeDef *)((sipWrapperType *)self)->type;
                                                      ^
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp: In function ‘const QMetaObject* get_qmetaobject(pyqtWrapperType*)’:
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp:583:52: error: ‘pyqt5ClassTypeDef’ was not declared in this scope
     return reinterpret_cast<const QMetaObject *>(((pyqt5ClassTypeDef *)((sipWrapperType *)pyqt_wt)->type)->static_metaobject);
                                                    ^
../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_types.cpp:583:71: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     return reinterpret_cast<const QMetaObject *>(((pyqt5ClassTypeDef *)((sipWrapperType *)pyqt_wt)->type)->static_metaobject);
                                                                       ^
Makefile:1892: recipe for target 'qpycore_types.o' failed
make[1]: *** [qpycore_types.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/robin/Develop/py_todo_env/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtCore'
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered' failed
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I have tried different versions of sip and pyqt5, some work, for example pyqt 5.10, but there is no QtWebEngineWidgets module I can import, so something wrong there as well.. Why is it so hard to get this right?

Comment: Have you tried installing PyQt5 through your Linux package manager? Usually there is a separate package there for the webengine widgets which you also need to install. Depends on what version of Linux you are running though...

Comment: Ok, but how does that work with my virtual enviroment? I just want this installation there and not system wide. I use Linux Mint 18

Comment: Yeah it's a pain, sorry. They've made it easier with Python 3.5+ as it can be installed with pip, but otherwise all the solutions are a bit hacky. Sorry I can't be of more help, maybe someone else has the answer though!

Comment: Yes, why not python 3. Just to get it to work. Thanks!